# TestNG Error: Not able to run TestNG ,getting Reference to undefined variable surefireArgLine?

Tags: java, testng

Here is my pom.xml code. While debugging as TestNG getting

> "Reference to undefined variable surefireArgLine"

Googled and tried some solutions. By removing below line,

> ${surefireArgLine}

getting below error

> "Error: Could not find or load main class argLine"

still facing issue.

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after unchecking the checkbox near argLine in
Window->Preferences->TestNG->Maven.